# MVVM Light Messenger Generic Method

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying to create a generic method that would allow my ObservableCollections to subscribe for changes and update themselves.

My Generic function is;

```
    public void SubscribeCollectionForUpdates<CType>(ObservableCollection<CType> collection, object receiver)
    {

        Messenger.Default.Register<AddedMessage<CType>>(receiver, (p) => {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(p.AddedEntitiy.ToString());
            collection.Add(p.AddedEntitiy);

        });
    }
```

my 'AddedMessage' class is;

```
public class AddedMessage<T>
{
    public T AddedEntitiy { get; set; }
}
```

and I will be sending messages as;

```
    Messenger.Default.Send<Messages.AddedMessage<MyType>>(new Messages.AddedMessage<MyType>() { 
AddedEntitiy = MyEntity 
});
```

I noticed that whenever I try to access the collection when registering for receive messages, I don't get any messages. (not registering properly?)

```
collection.Add(p.AddedEntitiy);
```

part in

```
    public void SubscribeCollectionForUpdates<CType>(ObservableCollection<CType> collection, object receiver)
    {

        Messenger.Default.Register<Messages.AddedMessage<CType>>(receiver, (p) => {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(p.AddedEntitiy.ToString());
            collection.Add(p.AddedEntitiy);

        });
    }
```

If I remove collection.Add(p.AddedEntitiy); and replace with MessageBox.Show() ore something, this works.. But whenever I access the collection not only to add, even if I d collection.Clear(), I do not get the message.

Can someone please help me? This is driving me crazy.